# Checksums incorrect in install4j 8.0.2 fpr notarised dmg files?

Tags: macos, install4j, macos-catalina

I get checksums (sha 256) for the build, but they are not the correct ones of the files.
Those checksums are part of `updates.xml` and `sha256sums` contain the same wrong checksums.
This is only the case for notarised dmg files (for macOS).

After notarisation xcode will add a special signature so that offline installation on macOS is possible. This obviously alters the file and thereby the checksum. Maybe install4j uses the sum before the notarisation is done? Or am I missing something?

The same is true for md5 checksums.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in install4j 8.0.3.

Comment: I see. The checksums in the two files are correct now but not in `updates.xml`. And `version` is set to `0.5&#xD;` instead of just `0.5`.

Comment: There are no checksums in updates.xml. And where do you get a line feed in the version? Do you maybe pass this version from outside?

Comment: There are checksums and the next release will fix the problem. The line feed is in the file from which I load the value. I simply removed it. I don't know why we didn't have this problem in earlier versions. Maybe it was trimmed.